# JSON DDL request failed - pipeline rowset is missing

Tags: azure-analysis-services, xmla

**Objective**
Refresh a partition using a query (override). Using these as a guide:

- https://www.sqlbi.com/articles/using-process-add-in-tabular-models/
- https://gist.github.com/dgosbell/a7bc9fe9ff5a99fdb4df5819b8760217#file-refresh-with-override-example-txt

*Apparently the MS example is not correct: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/bi-reference/tmsl/refresh-command-tmsl#examples*

**TMSL Script**

```
{
  "refresh" : {
    "type" : "add",
    "objects" : [{
        "database" : "dbname",
        "table" : "tblname"
      }
    ],
    "overrides" : [{
        "partitions" : [
          {
            "originalObject" : {
              "database" : "dbname",
              "table" : "tblname",
              "partition" : "partname"
            },
            "source" : {
              "query" :
              "SELECT * FROM source.view WHERE date_field = '2014-12-06'"
            }
          }
        ]
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

**Error Message**

```
The JSON DDL request failed with the following error: Failed to execute XMLA. Error returned: 'The Process command for partition 'partname' in table 'tblname' cannot be executed because the pipeline rowset is missing.
'..

Technical Details:
RootActivityId: 89a6f9ac-e5d4-4eaa-b049-455190039b4b
Date (UTC): 6/28/2019 3:20:36 PM
  0: PFError::SetLastError() line 2158 + 0x0 (sql\picasso\engine\src\pf\eh\pferror.cpp)
  1: PFSetLastError() line 2906 + 0x0 (sql\picasso\engine\src\pf\eh\pferror.cpp)
  2: ConvertExceptionsToPFResult<<lambda_764f81a97ea803a6bb1663c7971ce151> >() line 424 + 0x34 (sql\picasso\engine\src\pf\kernel\shared\pfshmacros.inl)
  3: PFSetLastErrorExTag() line 3461 + 0x2e (sql\picasso\engine\src\pf\eh\pferror.cpp)
  4: 0x00007FFAB599CC7E (symbolic name unavailable)
```

**Other Info**
Executed on SSMS directly and in Powershell (via Runbook) with same error message.

**Question**
What does this error message mean exactly? *(It is very hard to find
helpful documentation.)* Or, is there an alternative solution to refreshing
a partition using a query override?

Answer (score 1):

- You can only use either a Query or M partition sources
- If you are using an M partition source the syntax is:
  "source":{
  "type":"m",
  "expression":"…"
  }
- And if you are using a Query partition source the syntax is:
  "source":{
  "type":"query",
  "query":"…",
  "dataSource":"…"
  }